# Stream content from Android device to Apple TV

Tags: android, streaming, apple-tv

Is it possible to stream content from an Android app to Apple TV? Any API or 3rd party library?

Comment: you should not ask for a library here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to use LG's Connect SDK to get my Android app to stream to Apple TV. http://www.svlconnectsdk.com/

Comment: @moyo I ran into a roadblock, latest TV OS version requires device verification so we can't use this SDK on the newest generation of Apple TV's. On top of that, doesn't look like the SDK is supported by devs any more,